# Deploying Rails 3 on Dreamhost with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, dreamhost

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app using Capistrano (it's my first time using Capistrano).

I have a Dreamhost Private Server which is using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.3 (according to http://rails.dreamhosters.com/)

I've followed Dreamhost's Capistrano setup instructions (http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Capistrano)

When I run "cap deploy:migrations" I get this error:

```
[out :: xxx.com] Could not find i18n-0.5.0 in any of the sources
** [out :: xxx.com] Try running `bundle install`
```

Am I right in thinking that when deploying, bundle install should run automatically?
Not exactly sure where i18n is coming from either as I haven't added it anywhere.

Has anyone experienced this before or have any experience deploying Rails 3 to Dreamhost?

Comment: Same issue here on a shared host. I think it migt be caused by the versions of Bundler and Rubygems not playing nice to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you required the bundler cap tasks in your deploy.rb?

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

Comment: Dreamhost support got back to me with this "-Sorry about that, I needed to create a symlink to bundle.Give it a try now and write back in if you're still having an issue." Also included your bundler suggestion and that did the trick. Thanks